# Getting contacts of all the users with domain level accesToken in azure

Tags: azure, office365

Is there a way , where we could get/write the contacts of all the users in a domain with a domain level access token.

Currently I found that we could get the domain level access token for the organization using admin consent.

But this access token will not have any details about the user.
So how do we specify for which user , we are trying to get the contacts ?

Is there a way , where we can use the tenant-id and the user-id to get the  user specific access token without having him signed in even once but with an admin consent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did ‘domain level access token’ means you check the application permission to read the all contacts information like figure below:
[image]

The Office 365 API and Microsoft Graph API support get the personal contacts. The difference between the token get from “Authorization Code Grant Flow” and “Client Credentials” is that we need to specify the user context via the **ID** or **userPrincipalName** instead of the alias **me**:

REST API:

```
GET /me/contacts
GET /users/<id | userPrincipalName>/contacts
```

Sample Request:

```
GET /Users/fx@msdnofficedev.onmicrosoft.com/contacts
```

And if you were developing a single tenant scenario, since the application already register on the Azure AD tenant, there is no need to give the consent again.

Otherwise if you were developing an muti-tenant application, when the app run the first time, the user need admin privilege to give the consent for the application for "Read contacts in all mailboxes".

More detail about Microsoft Graph permission scopes, you can refer to link below:
https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes